# Barcode scanner plugin windows phone 8 doesnt execute callback

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, barcode-scanner

Hello im trying to use the cordoba plugin for barcode scanner windows phone 8, using mobilefirst 7.1, and after the plugin read de barcode correctly (i just put some breakpoints and the e.Barcode have the barcode value), the plagin

```
private void TaskCompleted(object sender, BarcodeScannerTask.ScanResult e)
        {
            PluginResult result;

            switch (e.TaskResult)
            {
                case TaskResult.OK:
                    result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, JsonHelper.Serialize(new BarcodeResult(e.Barcode)));
                  //  result.Message = ;
                    break;
                case TaskResult.Cancel:
                    // If scan is cancelled we return PluginResult.Status.OK with Message contains cancelled: true
                    // See plugin docs https://github.com/MSOpenTech/BarcodeScanner#using-the-plugin
                    result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, JsonHelper.Serialize(new BarcodeResult()));
                  //  result.Message =;
                    break;
                default:
                    result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,"Error default");
                    break;
            }

            DispatchCommandResult(result);
        }
```

the code enters to TaskResult.OK, and then create the response object correctly, next: execute DispatchCommandResult(result) and returns to my javascript code, but the callbacks funtions were never called.

Any help?

Comment: Which barcode plug-in are you using...

Comment: If you try the same in a pure Cordova sample , does it work? Is the issue only when running within MFP 7.1 WP8 application?

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Comment: @user2449016 and what about the question of - does it fail also without MFP in the picture...?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide the web part (the JS implementation) it is difficult to know why it is not calling the callback function.

My suggestion to you then is to look at the Cordova plug-ins tutorial for Windows Phone 8 and verify that you have implemented the JS part correctly.

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/windows-phone-8-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

```
function sayHello() {
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exe(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "SayHelloPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    WL.SimpleDialog.show(
        "Response from plug-in", data,
        [{text: "OK", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("Ok button pressed");}}]
    );
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    WL.SimpleDialog.show(
        "Response from plug-in", data,
        [{text: "OK", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("Ok button pressed");}}]
    );
}
```